# How to add file_upload in php.ini

Tags: php

I was doing some codes for uploading images/file etc into database. I already found a website where I can start coding with but then the first instructions said change file_upload from "Off" to "On" in `php.ini`. While I'm searching the words(file_upload) in `php.ini`, its missing or not exist. Perhaps I need to set it up on my own but I have no idea where and what should I put in there. I'm using `XAMPP` with `PHP5.6.3` . Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.file-uploads

You need to add this:

```
file_uploads = On
```

to your `php.ini` file

Comment: But I don't get it because there are many lines of codes there mate. Perhaps there should be like body { <code> } things so I can notice that is the place where I should put it.

Comment: search for `[PHP]` - should be at the top. Add that line anywhere before the next `[something]` block (in my case it's `[CLI Server]`)

Comment: I will get back to you on this, see if it works. Thank you! :)

Comment: I have that line just above `; Fopen wrappers ;`