# move_uploaded_file() can't upload files in a Hosting Server

Tags: php, html, ajax, upload

In my localhost server, with apache installed, I can upload files fine. But when I move everything to a hosting server (like Altervista.org) files doesn't upload.

**Here's the html code:**

```
<form id="fileupload" action="" method="POST">
  <input id="filesupload" type="file" multiple name="files" accept=".jpg" accessKey="PDF"/>
  <button id="MegaUpload" type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" onclick="conversion()">
</form>
```

Assuming that HTML Works well, I transfer everything in an AJAX and I can connect fine to the server.
PHP code can receive the input file as well, but when I try to do the upload, it doesn't work.

**Here's PHP code:**

```
 if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['users'])) {
       setcookie('users', md5(time()/1234), time() + (86400), "/");
    }

    if (!file_exists('files/uploads/' . $_COOKIE['users'] . '/')) {
      mkdir("files/uploads/" . $_COOKIE['users'], 0755);
      mkdir("files/uploads/" . $_COOKIE['users'] . "/tmp", 0755);
    }
    $target_dir = 'files/uploads/' . $_COOKIE['users'] . '\/tmp\/';
    for ($s=0; $s <= 10; $s++) {
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"][$s]);
       if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"][$s], 
  $target_file)) {
      //ok
       }
       else{
         //something wrong
       }
    }

 }
```

Again: Assuming that AJAX works fine (because I tested, and server receives the files I input), why in the hosting server it doesn't work?

It creates directories perfectly fine, there are directory permissions too, as you can see, and I checked in FileZilla if every `.php` files is setted to '0755'.

If you can't understand what's going on, I can post the AJAX part if you wish.
Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I edited the PHP part, so you know is a loop.

I added the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` as you said but still no result.

I forgot to put the `multiple` part on the HTML too.

**Here's the AJAX part as you asked:**

```
$("#filesupload").change(function(evnt) {

var fd = new FormData();
for (var s = 0; s < ins; s++) {
 fd.append("fileToUpload[]", document.getElementById('filesupload').files[s]);
}

$.ajax({
      url: 'upload.php', // point to server-side PHP script
      dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      data: fd,
      type: 'post',
      async: false,
      success: function(result){
        alert(result);
      },
      error: function(result) {
          alert(result);
      }
   });

}
```

I tested with alerts and echos, and I know the servers receives the file(s), but it doesn't upload.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201944/discussion-on-question-by-emasiena-move-uploaded-file-cant-upload-files-in-a).

Answer (score 0):

Create a

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

file on the hosting server and check the section *file_uploads*. This should be on *ON*.

If it is *OFF* or *FALSE* you may have no rights for a file upload. For this you should contact the admin of the hosting server. If you are the root, you can set this status to *ON* using this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433932/how-to-add-file-upload-in-php-ini)

Comment: I really thought this was the answer, but unluckly it still doesn't work, because the _file_uploads_ part in the _php.ini_ was already set in _ON_ in the hosting server.

Comment: Please check the file permissions on the folder once. You may not have write permission. The numeric value should be 644.

Comment: Checked once again, I also put the numeric value '0777' in all folders but still no answer on that. Should I put some permission of the execution on files? I see them still in '0644' tho...

Comment: Maybe you should create a new file and build a very simple framework. Create a form in HTML and link the form with a submit to new a PHP file. So you can debug it better and may find an error in the source code. Maybe this link will help you: [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)